# Simulating Turtlebot with Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, kinect, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm interested in programming Turtlebot in gazebo environment. I've finished the basic stuff on its tutorial page however I'm interested in doing more advanced stuff.

For example, I want to get data from either its virtual Kinect or a real one and then program it with C++ to function it as an obstacle avoiding robot.

Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114751/simulating-turtlebot-with-gazebo/) by [SpiderRico](https://answers.ros.org/users/10046/spiderrico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm assuming you mean that you've brought up the robot as in here: http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator

You'll need to go through the tutorials for gazebo and navigation to bring those capabilities together.

You'll want a more complicated world (from gazebo tutorials) and navigation (from http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0